# How to convert multi-file LaTeX documents using the pandoc API?

Tags: haskell, pandoc

I'm curious how I can convert a multi-file document in LaTeX to some other format using the Haskell pandoc API. I see there is [readLaTeX](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-2.10.1/docs/Text-Pandoc-Readers.html#v:readLaTeX) function, but this accepts a single `Text` value as a parameter instead of e.g. `[Text]`. What is the correct way to handle this more general situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the code, inclusion of other LaTeX documents with `\input{...}`, etc. is handled by searching for the documents using the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable as a colon-separated search path (or just checking the current directory, if `TEXINPUTS` isn't defined).

Truth be told, that's not a great way of doing it.  (To remain compatible with normal TeX stuff, it should be using the TeX `kpathsea` library to parse `TEXINPUTS`.)

But, if you make sure `TEXINPUTS` is either blank or includes `.` as one of its colon-separated components, and ensure you switch to the directory where all the files are, if you pass the text of the main file in to `readLaTeX`, it should "just work".

Comment: The idea behind pandoc is to translate LaTeX documents without requiring a TeX installation (or any component thereof). So binding to `kpathsea` would seem like the exact wrong thing to do.